# Why splitting script closing tag in a string?

Tags: javascript, tags

I am working on an asp.net project and on part of it, I needed to print a part of the page which contains an image using javascript. After some digging, I found a code and it works fine.

```
<script>


function VoucherSourcetoPrint(source) {
    return "<html><head><script>function step1(){\n" +
            "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
            "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}" +
            "\n</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" + <%-- lokk this line--%>
            "<img src='" + source + "' style='width: 300px; height: 150px; margine:none;' /></body></html>";
}

function VoucherPrint(source) {    
    Pagelink = "about:blank";
    var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
    pwa.document.open();
    pwa.document.write(VoucherSourcetoPrint(source));
    pwa.document.close();
}


</script>
```

As you can see on the first function it is returning a string and in that there is a script closing tag, which is written as `</scri" + "pt>`, first I thought it was a mistake and tried removing the extra quotes and plus sign and then the string showing error.

[image]

I am confused, why is it have to be like `</scri" + "pt>`??

Comment: To avoid an HTML parser from reading this JavaScript code and interpreting it as HTML.

Comment: then why script starting tag is not like that?

Comment: Because the HTML parser doesn't search for a starting script tag from within a script.

Comment: You only need to stop the closing tag from closing the `<script>` tag prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the HTML parser will find the sequence of characters "`</script>`" and **end the script element**. It will then pass invalid JavaScript to the JavaScript parser.

Here is a simplified example:

```
<script>console.log("</script>");</script>
▲       ▲           ▲▲        ▲  ▲
1       2           34        5  6
```

1. Script element start tag.
2. Begining of JavaScript (`console.log("` - not a compilable script).
3. End of JavaScript
4. Script element end tag
5. Text to show as plain text in the HTML document (`");`)
6. Script end for with no matching open tag. Discarded by HTML parser as an error.

A more elegant approach is to just escape the `/`:

```html
<script>console.log("<\/script>");</script>
```